# Conditional print based on array content in bash or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an input file with following contents:

```
SS SC
a 1
b 2
d 5
f 7
```

I have an input bash array as follow:

```
echo "${input[*]}"
a b c d e f
```

I need to create an output to:

*1. print the all elements of the array in 1st column

2. In second column, I need to print 0 or 1, based on the presence of the element.*

To explain this, in the input array called `input`, I have `a,b,c,d,e,f`. Now `a` is present in input file, so the output should be `a 1`, whereas `c` is missing in the input file, so the output should be `c 0` in the output.

Eg: Expected result:

```
SS RESULT
a 1
b 1
c 0
d 1
e 0
f 1
```

Tried, to `split` the bash array in an attempt to iterate over it, but its printing for each line(the way awk works), its getting too difficult to handle.
awk -v par="${input[*]}" 'BEGIN{ n = split(par, a, " ")} {for(i=0;i<=n;i++){printf "%s\n", a[i]}}'  input

I am able(missing header) to do this with `bash` for loop and some `grep`: But hoping `awk` would be shorter, as I need to put this in a `yaml` file so need to keep it short.

```
for item in ${input[@]};do 
     if ! grep -qE "^${item}" input ;then
        echo "$item 0";
     else 
        echo "$item 1";
     fi;
done

a 1
b 1
c 0
d 1
e 0
f 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk` to store the values in the first column of the file in an associative array and then see if the elements of the array exist in it:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=(a b c d e f)

awk 'BEGIN { print "SS", "RESULT" }
     FNR == NR { vals[$1] = 1; next }
     { print $0, $0 in vals }
    ' input.txt <(printf "%s\n" "${input[@]}")
```

---

Or doing the the same thing in pure `bash`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=(a b c d e f)

declare -A vals
while read -r v _; do
    vals[$v]=1
done < input.txt

echo "SS RESULT"
for v in "${input[@]}"; do
    if [[ -v vals[$v] ]]; then
        printf "%s 1\n" "$v"
    else
        printf "%s 0\n" "$v"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code snippet demonstrates how it can be achieved in perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @array = qw/a b c d e f/;
my %seen;

$seen{(split)[0]}++ while <DATA>;

say 'SS RESULT';
say $_, ' ', $seen{$_} ? 1 : 0 for @array;

__DATA__
SS SC
a 1
b 2
d 5
f 7
```

Output

```
SS RESULT
a 1
b 1
c 0
d 1
e 0
f 1
```